# collect rational factors in expression

Tags: sympy

Suppose I have the following:

```
a, b, c = symbols('a b c')
test = a / 2 + b / 2 + c
pprint(collect(test, Rational(1, 2)))

a   b    
─ + ─ + c
2   2
```

Is there a way to get SymPy to return something more along the lines of `1 / 2 * (a + b) + c`, or `(a + b) / 2 + c`?

Edit: `collect_const()` appears to work on my toy example, but doesn't seem to scale well to the real thing. Here is a better example.

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = symbols('a b c d e f')    
test = c / a + d / a + e / (a * b) + f / (a * b)
print(test)
```

I'd like to obtain something along the lines of `1 / a * (c + d + 1 / b * (e + f))`.
`collect(test, (1 / b, 1 / a))` gives me `(e/a + f/a)/b + (c + d)/a`, which is close, but I'd like to recursively collect `1 / a` in the first numerator. Furthermore, due to the nestedness of the expressions, it would be great to represent the denominators as a leading factor of e.g., `1 / a`, that is `1 / a * (b + c)` rather than `(b + c) / a`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use `str()` for this.
In you case,

```
str(collect(test, Rational(1, 2)))
```

gives output

```
'a/2 + b/2 + c'
```

For the exprerssion you mentioned, I would use

```
str(Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Add(Mul(Rational(1, 2), Symbol('f_2')), Mul(Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_5'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_6'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_7'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_8'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1)))))))), Add(Mul(Rational(1, 2), Symbol('p_2')), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_6'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_8'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('a_2'), Integer(-1)), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_2'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_1'), Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('a_2'), Integer(-1)), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_4'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_1'), Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))))), Mul(Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_5'), Symbol('x_6'), Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2'))), Mul(Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Pow(Symbol('x_6'), Integer(2)), Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2'))), Mul(Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_6'), Symbol('x_8'), Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')))))
```

This gives me output as

```
'-(f_2/2 + (a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)*(x_5*(-t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*wBar) + x_6*(-o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*wBar) + x_7*(-t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*wBar) + x_8*(-o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*wBar)))*(p_2/2 + x_6*(a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)*(-o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*wBar) + x_8*(a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)*(-o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*wBar) + x_2*(a_1*a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)*(-o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*a_2*wBar) + x_4*(a_1*a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)*(-o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(-t_2 + 1))/(2*a_2*wBar)) + x_5*x_6*z_1*(a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)/wBar + x_6**2*z_1*(a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)/wBar + x_6*x_8*z_1*(a_2*(-f_2 + 1) + f_2)/wBar'
```

To get a simplified result I used `simplify() as well`.

```
str(simplify(Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Add(Mul(Rational(1, 2), Symbol('f_2')), Mul(Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_5'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_6'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_7'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_8'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1)))))))), Add(Mul(Rational(1, 2), Symbol('p_2')), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_6'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_8'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('a_2'), Integer(-1)), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_2'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_1'), Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Pow(Symbol('a_2'), Integer(-1)), Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_4'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_1'), Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2')), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('o'), Symbol('t_2'), Symbol('z_2'), Add(Symbol('s'), Integer(-1))), Mul(Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('t_2')), Integer(1))))))), Mul(Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_5'), Symbol('x_6'), Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2'))), Mul(Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Pow(Symbol('x_6'), Integer(2)), Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2'))), Mul(Pow(Symbol('wBar'), Integer(-1)), Symbol('x_6'), Symbol('x_8'), Symbol('z_1'), Add(Mul(Symbol('a_2'), Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('f_2')), Integer(1))), Symbol('f_2'))))))
```

which gave me

```
'-(a_2*wBar*x_6*z_1*(a_2*(f_2 - 1) - f_2)*(x_5 + x_6 + x_8) + (f_2*wBar + (a_2*(f_2 - 1) - f_2)*(x_5*(t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(t_2 - 1)) + x_6*(o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(t_2 - 1)) + x_7*(t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(t_2 - 1)) + x_8*(o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(t_2 - 1))))*(a_2*p_2*wBar + a_2*(x_6 + x_8)*(a_2*(f_2 - 1) - f_2)*(o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(t_2 - 1)) + (x_2 + x_4)*(a_1*a_2*(f_2 - 1) - f_2)*(o*t_2*z_2*(s - 1) + z_1*(t_2 - 1)))/4)/(a_2*wBar**2)'
```

Is this the expected result?

Comment: I'm looking for the denominators to be collected, i.e. `1 / 2 * (a + b) + c`.